# Unable to use JSTL format taglib with Spring MVC form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am changing some code from a home grown MVC to Spring 2.5 MVC. We have a form to edit an object, so I am using `formBackingObject()` in my controller to populate the form fields with the current values. In the old MVC, we used the JSTL `fmt` taglib to format date and money fields. This was nice because the formatting was in the presentation layer.

Now with Spring, the fields are populated correctly with `formBackingObject()`, but Spring doesn't recognize the the value attribute in the `form:input` element:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<form:form method="post" commandName="editProgramCommand" name="editTitleForm">
  <fmt:formatNumber type="NUMBER" value="${program.price}" var="formattedPrice" minFractionDigits="2" />
  <form:input path="price" id="price" value="${formattedPrice}" />
  ... other fields
</form:form>
```

Thoughts on how to properly format values in a Spring form? I'm not finding much on the web, so I figure its either a really simple syntax error, or I'm completely on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

Spring `form:input` recognize the value of the input from its `path` attribute and not from the `value` attribute. If you see the [spring form tld](http://code.google.com/p/java-education/source/browse/trunk/JPA-Spring-JSF/CZU-PEF-DataModelling/web-gui/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-form.tld?r=196), there is no attribute value for the form input tag.

1. One way which i think is format the values in the back end and bring and set it in the front end.
2. Otherwise you can use the conventional `spring:bind` instead of spring form. [Spring Bind Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html)